# OS X Core data not initilazing in ViewController but works in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

Im trying to load my core data to my ViewController. inside ViewDidLoad Method.

`NSLog(@"Stored Tasks.... %@",[TTDatabase getAllTasks]);`

but it always gives me `+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Tasks'`

but when i call same thing in AppDelegate, it works fine.

```
[TTDatabase sharedDatabaseWithManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSLog(@"Stored Tasks.... %@",[TTDatabase getAllTasks]); // This Works
```

and The other thing i found is when i run the app its initialize ViewController first then after that it will call AppDelegate.

what im doing wrong in this problem? how can i load data in my viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your core data stack out of the app delegate and into ’TTDatabase`. Then, as soon as the first instance is created, and wherever it's created from, it will be properly configured because it has no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway i found a tricky way of doing it. after AppDelegate initialized, ill be calling my Viewcontroller method from it.

```
[TTDatabase sharedDatabaseWithManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc loadData];
```